# Move "actions" dropdown in Lightning:datatable in front of other page elements

Tags: datatable

I'd like the "actions" dropdown menu on my lightning:datatable to appear above the component and other page elements so that it doesn't force the user to scroll down to see all of the options. 
[image]

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable_x
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
.THIS .slds-scrollable_y
{overflow-y:visible!important;overflow-x:visible!important;}
```